# text type column wasn't truncated as expected in mysql

Tags: mysql

**Text type column wasn't truncated as expected in mysql 5.7.17、5.7.29。the details are as below:**

[image]
[image]

[image]

According to the documentation, there should be a warning, but nothing happen.

[image]